# How to build an executable file from a maven gluonfx project [PARTIALLY SOLVED]

Tags: java, maven, build, gluonfx

I was not able to build an executable file from a maven/gluonfx project, but i partially solved opening x64 Native tools, using cd command to move into the gluonfx project folder and i used the

mvn gluonfx:build command to build the app. So everything works but, no fxml is loaded, just like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiB68.png)

but if i use mvn gluonfx:run command into intellij,everything works, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVqS0.png)

So if i try to use mvn gluonfx:nativerun command into x64 Native tools program, it gives me this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDXyV.png)

So probably there is a problem loading the FXML. If i try to run the app, using the mvn gluonfx:run command into the x64 Native tools program it still works. So i think that the problem is related with native run, and it has a problem loading the fxml in this configuration.

This is my pom file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.knnapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>knn-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>KNN-Application</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.16</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.15</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.knnapplication.KNNApplication</mainClassName>

    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>

                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.knnapplication.views.PrimaryPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.knnapplication.views.SecondaryPresenter</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

EXCEPTION:

```
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] nov 13, 2022 8:38:42 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @6e8dacdf'
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] nov 13, 2022 8:38:42 PM com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform <clinit>
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] INFO: [Gluon Attach] System Property javafx.platform is not defined. Platform will be set to Platform.DESKTOP
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] /com/knnapplication/views/primary.fxml:37
[dom nov 13 20:38:42 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]
```

LINE 37 of PRIMARY FXML

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOQ1E.png)

Comment: If you are on Windows, you need to install Visual Studio. See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows

Comment: @JoséPereda i’ve already installed it :( But still does not work

Comment: Do you use the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` terminal?

Comment: i don’t really know what are you talking about, i’ve installed vs 2019 and i use mvn command on IntelliJ

Comment: Just read carefully the link I mentioned above.

Comment: ok tnank you so much. I've read it, and i've changed the shell path, connecting it with VS path, but stilll not working and still gives me the same problem

Comment: @JoséPereda thank you so much for having helped me. I partially solved the problem, opening x64 Native tools command prompt. The problem now is that the .exe is generated but it does not show gui, or it shows it partially

Comment: If you run it with `mvn gluonfx:nativerun` you should see the output, and you will find probably an exception that explains the problem. Alternatively you can run your executable from command line like `myexe.exe 2> log.txt`, and then edit the log file to see it.

Comment: @JoséPereda if says IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/com/knnapplication/views/primary.fxml:37

Comment: Probably an issue with reflection. You can run `mvn gluonfx:runAgent` and then build the native image again

Comment: i've already tried, but it still gives me load exception

Comment: You need to post the full exception.

Comment: I've edited the post with the full exception

Comment: Is there anything more in the logs after that? Else post what is line 37 of `com/knnapplication/views/primary.fxml`

Comment: No, nothing more. I've just uploaded the line 37

Comment: UPDATE: if i build it with mvn gluonfx:build command it works, but I have three views, and just one them works, so if i click on a button that should show the second view, it show blank :(

Comment: You _need_ to run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` and _discover_ all possible scenarios of your app, so all uses of reflection are registered. Then run `mvn gluonfx:build` again.  That should work.